# I am not getting the data from this function into my fcm message receiver. why?

Tags: android

```
const request = require('request');     
request
(
  {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    headers:
    {
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      'Authorization':'key= server key'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify
    (
      {
        "registration_ids" : [token],
        "data" : 
        {
          "msg":"lattitude"
        },
        "time_to_live": 108
      }
    )
  },
  function(e1,r1,b1)
  {
    console.log(r1);
    console.log(b1);
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have used the correct server key from the same Firebase console that's used by your end in Android.

```
'Authorization':'key= server key'
```

Comment: Yes, that server key from my firebase "project server"  key.